# Finding rows that are missing specific value in a set

Tags: mysql

The database that I am using is MySQL. I have an `options` table that roughly looks like this

```
id          int(10) PRIMARY
annex_id    int(10)
title       varchar(255)
sort_order  INT(10) NOT NULL
```

Every annex (annex_id) has bunch of options enumerated by `sort_order` column which varies from 1 to N and are controlled by humans.

Due to software bug from a couple of months a lot of annexes do not have an option with sort_order == 1 but rather start from 2 or 3.

What I want to do is get all the `annex_id`'s which contain options that do not have sort_order == 1. I'll show an exemplary table because I feel like I'm explaining it wrong (which could be the reason I can't come up with a query for it and I've been at it for hours).

| ID | Annex ID | Title | Sort Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 567 | Title #1 | 1 |
| 13 | 567 | Title #2 | 2 |
| 14 | 567 | Title #3 | 3 |
| 15 | 890 | Another title #1 | 2 |
| 16 | 890 | Another title #2 | 3 |

From the given table I pretty much want craft a query that would get annex id 890 because it doesn't have a row with sort order == 1.

The table has hundreds of thousands of rows and going at it by hand is insane. I've been dealing with databases for years and either I'm overthinking it or idk what but I can't come up with an efficient query to do this job.

Is it even possible to have a query like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have definitely more than one option here.  There is another method with grouping and aggregation and it uses conditional counting:

```
SELECT
  annex_id
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  annex_id
HAVING
  COUNT(CASE sort_order WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) = 0
;
```

The conditional counting itself has several ways of expressing in MySQL.  Instead of

```
COUNT(CASE sort_order WHEN 1 THEN 1 END)
```

you could also use any of these:

```
COUNT(IF(sort_order = 1, 1, NULL))
```

```
COUNT(sort_order = 1 OR NULL)
```

```
SUM(sort_order = 1)
```

But you could also take a completely different approach.  You could use the `EXCEPT` set operator to get the difference between the set of all `annex_id` values and the set of those that have `sort_order = 1`:

```
SELECT
  annex_id
FROM
  table

EXCEPT

SELECT
  annex_id
FROM
  table
WHERE
  sort_order = 1
;
```

Note that `EXCEPT` on its own stands for `EXCEPT DISTINCT`, which means that duplicate values are automatically eliminated.

Comment: Caveat:  `EXCEPT` was not implemented until MySQL 8.0.31 in 2022.  (MariaDB 10.3 implemented it in 2017.)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering, as per [matigo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/228577/matigo)'s instruction the query would look like the following

```
SELECT annex_id FROM table GROUP BY annex_id HAVING MIN(sort_order) > 1
```